# Android: What should the width of a dialog be?

Tags: android, dialog

I'm using an activity with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" to make it act as a dialog. What lies closest to the **native** behavior of dialogs: Should a dialog fill the screen (in width) or not? And should it grow dynamically if, for instance, a text box is filled up by typing?

My hunch is that the dialog should not fill the screen. I have tried to get this behavior, but whatever I do, on Android 2.2, the dialog width **seems to fill the parent**.

My layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:autoText="true" 
        android:text="@string/item_delete_dialog_label" 
        android:padding="5dip" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <Button android:id="@+id/yes" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/button_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/no" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/button_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've found many questions regarding making a dialog fill the screen in width, but none about making it wrap in width. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ButtonBar style makes the dialog much wider than it would be using standard buttons.  Changing the LinearLayout width to wrap_content won't affect the width of the dialog as it's merely filling the main LinearLayout container which is set to wrap_content - changing the button style will most definitely make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The general style for dialogs is to be just as big as they need to to enclose their children.  If the children don't take up the whole width, the dialog won't either.

Your problem might be that your LinearLayout has a width of fill_parent.  This means that it is going to take up as much space as is allowed.  Change the width the wrap_content, so it doesn't take up any more space than it needs.

Or, if your dialog is really that simple, just use an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).